# Use Promise Results

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make a table with links to pictures I'm returning from the following:

```
const listObjectPromise = async () => {
    const listObjects = await s3.listObjects(params).promise()
    
    if (listObjects){
        const objectNamesList = []
        for (var i = 0; i < listObjects.Contents.length; i++) {
                objectNamesList.push(listObjects.Contents[i].Key)
        }
        for(var i=0;i<objectNamesList.length;i++){
            objectNamesList[i]="addThisInFront"+objectNamesList[i];
        }
    return(objectNamesList)
    }  
}
```

I'm using the basic table from Material UI:

```
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData(here, 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData(here, 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData(here, 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData(here, 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData(here, 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];
```

and I'd like for each picture link in the array to be displayed in the spots that say "here" in the rows. How can I use the results from a promise in this way?

what I'm trying to end up with is something like this:

```
const rows = [
//for length of array from listObjectPromise
  createData(/*picture at i here*/, 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
];
```

EDIT
So I was able to use the first answer to do this:

```
const rows = async () => { 
  const images = await listObjectPromise()
  if(images){
      const rowsList = []
      for(var i=0; i<images.length;i++){
          rowsList.push(createData(images[i], 20, 20, 20, 30))
      }
      return(rowsList)
  }
}
```

I am now stuck with this error: "TypeError: array.map is not a function". The error is happening at this place in my code

```
function stableSort(array, comparator) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}
```

this function is called in the return with rows like this:

```
{stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
```

would I instead use something like rows() as the input in stableSort? I want the array returned from that promise to be input #1 for the stableSort function.

Comment: Why don't you try to see what's inside array ? The error is quite explicit here, array does not contain a map function so array is not an array

Comment: Oh I see. The promise is unresolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A promise contains the images once it's resolved, so you have to wait for it till it's resolved.

```
const images = listObjectPromise().then((data) => {
  // use data here
})
```

But a neater way is if the code you have calling it is also in an async function then you can do:

```
const example = async () => {
  const images = await listObjectPromise()

  // use images
}
```